# Excel sheet exported from ssrs. Pivot table and sorting functionality not working in sheet

Tags: ssrs-2008

msoffice2007. when report is exported from ssrs to excel sheet. the functions PIVOT Table and SORTING are not working, it is showing some error like:
""The PovitTable field name is not valid. To create a PovitTable report, you musr use data that is organized with labeled columns. If you are chanfing the name of a pivot table field you must type a new name for the field."" for PIVOT Table.

and ""The operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized."" for sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your report isn't perfectly aligned and it cause different cells in the table to get merged, what you should do is to look for the cells whom didn't got merged (in the excel sheet) , check their size in the report builder and change the other cells to that size.

additional tip, make sure that your data (table in this case) is aligned to the top left of the screen.